# Symfony 4.4 how to fetch specific rows from related entity that has ManyToOne relation?

Tags: php, sql-server, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a `User` entity and a `Hours` entity. One user can have multiple hours. So a OneToMany for user-hours. And a ManyToOne for hours-user.

I used the [symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/doctrine/associations.html) to create this. Symfony created this `getHours()` function in the `User` class for me that I want to use.

```php
/**
 * @return Collection|Hours[]
 */
public function getHours(): Collection
{
    return $this->hours;
}
```

I want to use this because I need to create a page where I show basicly all the user data that exists. So `Hours` is just one example of the many other entities that are connected with `User`. I thought, if I relate them all with `User`, I will only need to fetch/query `User` in my controller and from there call `$user->getHours()` and the other entities.

**Here comes the issue:**

`$user->getHours()` returns **ALL** the hours connected to this user. But I only want the hours between two specific dates. Basicly I want to know how to do a `WHERE` statement. But obviously **before** all the hours are fetched from db. Since I know I could do `getHours()` and then do if statements to filter out the hours between a date. I dont want that.

In essential I want this repository function below, but without the need to keep calling these seperately from the `User` object. In this functions case I need the user id, which I already have when calling the `User` object. I hope this is possible and makes sense.

```php
// Hours repository:
/**
 * Get hours registered by userID (id) which are registered on dates between date1 and date2.
 * 
 * Returns fields shown in ->select();
 * 
 * @return Hours[] Returns an array of Hours objects
 */
public function getHoursBetweenDate($id, $date1, $date2)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('h')
        ->select('h.id', 'h.project_id', 'h.date', 'h.hours', 'h.travel_time', 'h.submitted_by', 'h.approved_by')
        ->where('h.user = :id')
        ->andWhere('h.date between :date1 and :date2')
        ->setParameter('id', $id)
        ->setParameter('date1', $date1)
        ->setParameter('date2', $date2)
        ->addOrderBy('h.date', 'ASC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
}
```

I use SQL Server as db.

Comment: You should use the [Collection Criteria](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/doctrine-relations/collection-criteria) within your entity to fetch what you would like, in your instance you would need create criteria that is between dates..

Comment: @Bossman Hmm, maybe I asked the wrong question. I've looked into it and did some research into the code and how others are doing it etc. But for some reason it feels like it makes things just more complex than what I had before. Which is that no table was connected with one another. And I just query each table like the `getHoursBetweenDate` function. I hoped connecting the entities/tables would automate things but it does not seem like it. I want a cleaner/simpler/shorter way of retrieving all the data I need. This feels like a different route for the same solution. But maybe im wrong.

Comment: That's the way it is done. Doctrine is smart enough to cache and create the correct query for you in the background. You would only need to add an extra 2 or 3 lines to your *getHours()* function and add `use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria;` to the top of your entity...

Comment: @Bossman But how do I keep this dynamic? What if I later *do* want to have all hours. Or need a different criteria. Im all quite new to this tbh.

Comment: @Bossman Besides, are you saying that if I add 2/3 lines to the getHours() function, doctrine will change the query it's doing on the background? How does doctrine know the code? Because its connected with `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria`?

Comment: You can add as many functions as you like with whatever return data you need. So you can have for example: `getAllHours(){...`, `getWorkingHours() {...`. Working with collections with Doctrine is actually really powerful, its designed to make life easier :)

Comment: Yes. It might seem like magic, but that is the point in the library. You can check the Symfony profiler and see the queries it makes...

Comment: @Bossman okey tnx! I tried the profiler, but with my tables connected my whole code is broken :P. Anyway, I will try to make a working version in the way you said. Thanks for your help so far. Ill keep you updated.

Comment: @Bossman I've been working with it for some time now and come to the conclusion that I do not see how this improved my code. Either that or im missing something. I understand using relationships improves structure etc. but Symfony/Doctrine just doesn't seem to make it any easyer then it already was. I checked the profiler aswell, and it does not seem to make any less queries. Still thanks for your help though, atleast I learned something :)